# python: How can I resolve this error?

Tags: python

I don't know what to do with this function...the first one is solved but the other one is a mess and I only get 3 not 17.5

```
def split_on_separators(original, separators):
    """ (str, str) -> list of str

    Return a list of non-empty, non-blank strings from the original string
    determined by splitting the string on any of the separators.
    separators is a string of single-character separators.

    >>> split_on_separators("Hooray! Finally, we're done.", "!,")
    ['Hooray', ' Finally', " we're done."]
    """
    result = []
    newstring = ''

    for index,char in enumerate(original):
        if char in separators or index==len(original) -1:
            result.append(newstring)
            newstring=''
            if '' in result:
                result.remove('')
        else:
            newstring+=char
    return result
def average_sentence_length(text):
    """ (list of str) -> float

    Precondition: text contains at least one sentence. A sentence is defined
    as a non-empty string of non-terminating punctuation surrounded by 
    terminating punctuation or beginning or end of file. Terminating 
    punctuation is defined as !?.

    Return the average number of words per sentence in text.   

    >>> text = ['The time has come, the Walrus said\n',
         'To talk of many things: of shoes - and ships - and sealing wax,\n',
         'Of cabbages; and kings.\n'
         'And why the sea is boiling hot;\n'
         'and whether pigs have wings.\n']
    >>> average_sentence_length(text)
    17.5
    """
    words=0
    Sentences=0
    for line in text:
        words= words+1
    sentence=split_on_separators(text,'?!.')
    for sep in sentence:
        Sentences+=1

    ASL=words/Sentences
    return ASL
```

Comment: Have you tried to use the decimal division ``//`` operator, instead of the whole division operator ``/`` (the default one in python2)? Example: ``3/2 -> 1``

Comment: well it will only make it the same 3 but int not float

Comment: You just asked this an hour ago.

Comment: At least ask add some more details. You're not saying anything specific about parts you already know are wrong, such as the `for line in text`. Don't make people re-find the bugs.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get this error is the following line of code -

```
 for index,char in enumerate(original)
```

You are iterating over original which is a list not a string not a char, there for

```
char in separators
```

Would never be true and

```
len(original)
```

is 2 so you stop after 2 iterations. You need to iterate over each string in the text.

Answer (score 0):

They way you are separating the words are wrong. You were counting element count from the list instead of words.

```
Sentences=0
words = len(filter(None, re.split("[\n\r\s:\?.,-;]+", " ".join(text))))
##                     if you need  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ add more word separators here
sentence=split_on_separators(" ".join(text),'?!.')
for sep in sentence:
    Sentences+=1
ASL=float(words)/Sentences
print ASL
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of the functions have problem. So, instead of re-posting the same question, do some improvements in your code. Do some debugging to see where is the problem? Why are you nor getting the expected output?

```
import re

def split_on_separators(original, separators):
    """ (str, str) -> list of str

    Return a list of non-empty, non-blank strings from the original string
    determined by splitting the string on any of the separators.
    separators is a string of single-character separators.

    >>> split_on_separators("Hooray! Finally, we're done.", "!,")
    ['Hooray', ' Finally', " we're done."]
    """
    result = []
    newstring = ''

    for index,char in enumerate(original):
        if char in separators or index==len(original) -1:
            result.append(newstring)
            newstring=''
            if '' in result:
                result.remove('')
        else:
            newstring+=char
    return result
def average_sentence_length(text):
    """ (list of str) -> float

    Precondition: text contains at least one sentence. A sentence is defined
    as a non-empty string of non-terminating punctuation surrounded by 
    terminating punctuation or beginning or end of file. Terminating 
    punctuation is defined as !?.

    Return the average number of words per sentence in text.   

    >>> text = ['The time has come, the Walrus said\n',
         'To talk of many things: of shoes - and ships - and sealing wax,\n',
         'Of cabbages; and kings.\n'
         'And why the sea is boiling hot;\n'
         'and whether pigs have wings.\n']
    >>> average_sentence_length(text)
    17.5
    """
    words=0

    for line in text:
        # be careful here, kind of hard coded!
        line_values = list(filter(("-").__ne__, line.strip().split()))
        words += len(line_values)
    # I didn't call your function as that is erroneus
    #sentence=split_on_separators(''.join(text),'?!.')

    sentence =[x for x in re.compile('[.!?]').split(''.join(text).strip()) if x]    
    ASL=words/len(sentence)
    return ASL

text = ['The time has come, the Walrus said\n',
         'To talk of many things: of shoes - and ships - and sealing wax,\n',
         'Of cabbages; and kings.\n'
         'And why the sea is boiling hot;\n'
         'and whether pigs have wings.\n']
print (average_sentence_length(text))
```